# UITextView InputView Autocorrection and Autocapatilization

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitextfield, uitextview

I made a program for the iPad. The program uses `UITextView` Controller. I used my own `InputView` instead the default iPad keyboard. My problem is when I edit the `textview` using my `inputview`, I lost the AutoCorrection and AutoCapitalization features of the textview. Is there a way to have my own `textview` `inputview` and still have the auto correction and auto capitalization features? Please help

Comment: Unfortunately not, this is handled by the OS.

Comment: What do you mean by "own textview inputview". Have you subclassed the UITextView-class?

Comment: @Jens `UITextField` and `UITextView` have an `inputView` property of type `UIView` that can be shown instead of a keyboard.